# winform login using webrequest or webclient

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

From past few days i have been trying to login using webclient and webrequest but for some reason is dosen't work. Below is the code i am using to log in.

```
private class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    { }
    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer c)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = c;
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

        var castRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (castRequest != null)
        {
            castRequest.CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
        }

        return request;
    }
}
```

below is html form for post:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="field">
        <label>Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="username">
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <div style="float:left; width:102px;height:20px; display:block;">&nbsp;</div>

        <a class="button_forgot_password_blue" href="/my-account/forgotten-password"></a>
        <input type="submit" value="" class="button_login_blue" name="login">
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see the action block is totally empty how can i login into this.please help.

UPDATE : here is the code what i am trying to do.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
            {
                var values = new NameValueCollection
              {
                    { "username", "vallue" },
                    { "password", "value" },
              };
                client.UploadValues("http://www.1stchoice.co.uk/my-account/sign-in", values);
                 // If the previous call succeeded we now have a valid authentication cookie
                // so we could download the protected page
                string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.1stchoice.co.uk/request/stop/7854140");
                File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\clc.txt", result);   
            }

        }
```

Comment: If the action attribute is empty, the form will submit to the current page. You should be able to login by using the WebClient to POST to the page URL, passing the username and password as form data.

Comment: I did tried that but when i try to request to pages behind login.It always redirect me to the same login page mean login not successful.

Comment: Can you show the code for what you tried? It's impossible to diagnose otherwise.

Comment: Hi @pmcoltrane please can u check this what i am trying to do.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `UploadValues` to see if the server sent an error?